# C++ use std::chrono to measure execution of member functions in a nice way

Tags: c++, time, std, c++-chrono

I want to optimize my application, especially the execution speed of certain functions.

Imagine there is a class with some member functions

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    virtual ~Test();
    int init(int arg1, double arg2);

private:
    [...]
```

and in my constructor I call one of these methods

```
Test::Test()
{
    [...]
    int value = init(1, 1.2);
}
```

How can I measure the execution time of my method `init(...)` in a nice and clean way without breaking my program?

At the moment I use following code

```
Test::Test()
{
    [...]
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    int value = init(1, 1.2);

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = stop - start;
    std::cout << duration.count() * 1000 << "ms\n";
}
```

It works as expected but I think it is pretty messy and I want to have a "cleaner" solution.

Is there a way to have some kind of function which takes a member function and other parameters like so

```
int value = countTime(function, arg1, arg2);
```

I don't know whether it is possible to pass the return value from `function()` to `countTime()` in order to don't interrupt the workflow of my code.

**EDIT:**
This is my TimeMeasure class

```
namespace tools 
{
    class TimeMeasure 
    {
    public:
        TimeMeasure() 
        {
            m_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }

        virtual ~TimeMeasure()
        {
            m_stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> duration = m_stop - m_start;
            std::cout << duration.count() << "ms\n";
        }

    public:
        typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> HighResClock;

    private:
        HighResClock m_start;
        HighResClock m_stop;
    };

    template <typename T, typename F, typename... Args>
    auto measure(T *t, F &&fn, Args... args)
    {
        tools::TimeMeasure timeMeasure;
        return (t->*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

and in my constructor `Test()` I use the function `measure` this way

```
Test()
{
    [...]
    tools::measure(this, Test::init, filepath);
}
```

`int init(const std::string& filepath) const` takes here a string to a file. So in my case it's just one argument

Unfortunately I get a `invalid use of non-static member function 'int init(const string&) const'` error

I would wonder if a constructor is not a member function. So why do I get this error?

**EDIT 2:**

According to OznOg's answer I just forgot to hand in a pointer to my function.

So this would be the correct function call

```
tools::measure(this, &Test::init, filepath);
```

Comment: Assign `stop - start` into a `std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>`, and drop the `* 1000`.  Let `<chrono>` do these conversions for you.  If you get into the habit of doing that, when things get _really_ complicated, you'll have fewer coding errors.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks for the advice! I didn't know this

Comment: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_80.html

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've already discovered the tool. Unfortunately that would be a bit too much for my needs. I only want to measure certain functions. In addition, `gprof` seems to generate a relatively large overhead.

Comment: It's not "too much", it's exactly the proper tool for profiling function execution, rather than sprinkling time measurements through your application which is prone to all sorts of errors. Granted, it slows your program down, so you won't get an absolute speed, but an absolute speed is useless anyway (your program will run on more than one PC, right?) - you need to know which function is currently slower than all the other functions, and for that it's spot on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe you're right. Maybe the tool is just right for many. But I want to make the measurements at runtime and not after finishing my program. I want to use some of the measurements in my program. And as I said, gprof has a noticeable overhead.

Comment: Okay then, sounds like you're onto the right path for your requirements.

Comment: Probably, but thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a class like:

```
struct MeasureTime {
    MeasureTime() : _start(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) {}

    ~MeasureTime() {
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> duration = stop - _start;
        std::cout << duration.count() * 1000 << "ms\n";
    }
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>  _start;
};
```

and simply use it in your code:

```
Test::Test()
{
    MeasureTime mt;
    [...]
    { //or even this for just the init call
    MeasureTime mt2;
    int value = init(1, 1.2);
    }
}
```

IMHO it is less intrusive than what you proposed.

If you really want a function, you may try a wrapper like:

```
template <class T, class F, class... Args>
auto MeasureTimeFn(T *t, F &&fn, Args&&... args) {
    MeasureTime timer;
     return (t->*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And call it like:

```
int value = MeasureTimeFn(this, &Test::init, 1, 1.2);
```

but not sure it is really much better.

You can try to hide thing with a macro:

```
#define MEASURE(f, ...) \
  MeasureTimeFn(this, &std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>::f, __VA_ARGS__)
```

this way you can write

```
int value = MEASURE(init, 1, 1.2);
```

what is quite like what you asked for, but only works inside member functions, with member functions (non static).

Anyway probably a good place to start with.

*** EDIT***
If you can modify inheritance of you class, you may try

```
template<class T>
struct MeasureTool {
    template <class F, class... Args>
    auto measure(F &&fn, Args&&... args) {
        tools::TimeMeasure timeMeasure;
        return (static_cast<T*>(this)->*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

class Test : public MeasureTool<Test>
{
public:
    Test();
    virtual ~Test() {}
    int init(const std::string &filepath) { _path = filepath; return 0; }
    const auto &getPath() const { return _path; }
private:
    std::string _path;

};

Test::Test()
{
    std::string filepath("/some/where");
    int value = measure(&Test::init, filepath);
    measure(&Test::getPath);
}
```

And, this time, seems to match your very first requirement (but is quite intrusive...)

now, it's all in your hands :)

Comment: At the moment I do it in a similar way. But if I let the destructor do the work for me and put `int value = init(...)` into scopes I will lose `value`. There is a reason why I return something and save it in a variable. I want to do something with it later on in my `Test()` constructor.

I thought it would be nice to change as little as possible in my productive code

Comment: with statement expression, you may remove the template function, not sure this would be better (less portable)

Comment: I like the updated way. I think it is less confusing if you just want to measure time of function and not change the code a lot
Unfortunately I got a `invalid use of non-static member function ‘[...]'` error while compiling. I thought that the pointer to my member function should be enough in order to call it?

Comment: you should show the code somewhere, I think you are not calling the macros from a member function.

Comment: ok, there was a typo; the macro was ok, but not the direct use the was a missing __&__ ; you should try with  `int value = MeasureTimeFn(this, &Test::init, 1, 1.2);`

Comment: That's a great way to achieve my goal. Thanks for your help! I could have really come up with the pointer to the function myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I use always [Boost.Timer](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.timer).

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

...
boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  funct();

std::cout << timer.format();
```

It shows the **wall**, the **user**, and the **system** time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use such implementation:

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<typename std::result_of<Fn&&(Args...)>::type>::value, 
    std::tuple<std::chrono::duration<double>, typename std::result_of<Fn&&(Args...)>::type>
>::type
countTime(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto fnret = std::forward<Fn>(fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::make_tuple(stop - start, fnret);
}

template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<Fn&&(Args...)>::type>::value, 
    std::tuple<std::chrono::duration<double>>
>::type
countTime(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::forward<Fn>(fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::make_tuple(stop - start);
}

template<typename R, class C, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<R, void>::value,
    std::tuple<std::chrono::duration<double>, R>
>::type
countTime(R (C::*fn)(Args...), C& obj, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto fnret = (obj.*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::make_tuple(stop - start, fnret);
}

template<class C, typename... Args>
std::tuple<std::chrono::duration<double>>
countTime(void (C::*fn)(Args...), C& obj, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    (obj.*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::make_tuple(stop - start);
}
```

This will return a tuple with one member duration in case of void (*)(...) functions and a tuple with duration and return type in case of functions returning smth. It works with std::bind and member functions. Probably the overload may be merged into one or two implementations, but i have no idea how to do that.

Example call:

```
auto ret = countTime([](int a) -> int { 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(a)); 
    return a * 2;
}, 10);
std::cout << "function executed in: " <<
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::get<0>(ret)).count() <<
    " milliseconds." << std::endl;
std::cout << "function returned: " << std::get<1>(ret) << std::endl;
```

Simpler example call:

```
auto ret = countTime(&Test::init, *this, 1, 1.2);
int value = std::get<1>(ret);

std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::get<0>(ret)).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
```

Simple simpler example call, assuming `int init(int, int)` function:

```
auto ret = countTime(init, 1, 1.2);
int value = std::get<1>(ret);

std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::get<0>(ret)).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
```

Live version available at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/HkkgJCYiX).