# Program that measuers the time taken by the user to input a value

Tags: c++, time

I want to make a program that measures the time an user takes to input a value. For example, let's say the program outputs something that prompts the user to enter a value. Now, i want to measure the time the user takes to input the value. Is there a way to measure the time taken by the user to input something? I'm working in C++.

Comment: `std::chrono` will be useful. [Date and time utilities - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: What did you try? Have you tried googling? There's a whole standard header dedicated to times dates and durations. The `chrono` header.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: maybe you can have a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905915/c-use-stdchrono-to-measure-execution-of-member-functions-in-a-nice-way/52906064#52906064